# Why does my viewport look different when I deploy to heroku?

Tags: html, mobile, heroku, responsive-design, viewport

I have a simple web app that I am deploying to `heroku`.  In my html, I am have the meta information about the viewport:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">
    <title>Notify</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap.css">
</head>
```

Here is my server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static('./public'));
```

When I access it from my `iphone` being served locally, it looks fine.  I don't have to pinch and zoom to use my app.

I then deploy it to `heroku`.  When I access the app it is extremely small.  I have to pinch and zoom to be able to use the app.  What could be causing this?

Comment: It's just a try, but have you considered using , instead of ; to separate the configurations in your viewport content?

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work

Comment: Not sure if you're hosting through goDaddy but I had this same issue and what I had to do change the domain forwarding "with masking" to "permanent" and everything suddenly worked perfectly

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, but I didn't use `goDaddy`. From *Chrome DevTools*' *Device Toolbar*, I can verify that my page scaled ~95% locally, but after deployed on Heroku it scaled to ~78%. Still don't know why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few details you could check.

(1) Rewrite the head of your page as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Notify</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Note that I've declared the doctype, charset, replaced the semi-colons with commas in your viewport meta tag (as suggested by [brance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2746366/brance) , and changed `user-scalable=0` to `user-scalable=no`

Clear your cache and check.

(2)  Use webinspector to triple check that you have no 404s and that all the files, especially css are loading and that there isn't a path issue

(3) If still no joy, post a URL

Good luck!

Comment: I fixed all of those items and it didn't change anything.  I then cloned the repo (including your changes) and pushed them to `Heroku`.  The new site works fine, but the old one is still busted and all I did was copy the directory and calls to the `db`.  I don't know what changed to fix it.  I am going to wait a few days to see if anyone can tell me what happened, and if not, I will give you the bounty.

Comment: Good to hear that your site is behaving now ;)

Comment: I just figured out the problem.  I am forwarding through `godaddy` and that is where the issue is.  When I hit the `heroku` link direct, it looks fine.  When I hit the `godaddy` forwarded address, it has the issue.  Any idea on that?

Comment: Check if GoDaddy is loading the forwarded domain inside an iframe. That would be a problem.

Comment: It does use an iframe.  So that is the real issue here.

Comment: It won't let me award until an hour has passed.

Comment: When using GoDaddy and Heroku together, using forwarding with masking (which is the cause of this iframe and meta tag issue) is seemingly the only way to be able to use naked URLs (e.g. URLs without the 'www'). Turning off masking means the user will see 'www' after they have been redirected. Has anyone found a workaround for this?